NextJS app directory cannot find Clerk middleware
I'm using NextJS app dir, with no src dir and Clerk. 
Above I listed the location of the middleware page.
digest: "4053108776"
 ⨯ Error: Clerk: auth() was called but Clerk can't detect usage of clerkMiddleware() (or the deprecated authMiddleware()). Please ensure the following:
-  clerkMiddleware() (or the deprecated authMiddleware()) is used in your Next.js Middleware.
- Your Middleware matcher is configured to match this route or page.
- If you are using the src directory, make sure the Middleware file is inside of it.

For more details, see https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs

    at $$ACTION_0 (./lib/checkUser.ts:18:89)
    at Header (./components/globals/Header.tsx:18:81)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "4053108776"
 GET /_next/static/chunks/app/invalidateCache.js.map 404 in 147ms
 ✓ Compiled in 43ms (330 modules)

I can't figure it out how to deal with this. I've seen alor of posts on this forum, tried many, but not working.

So far, the folder structure looks okay. Can you update your question and add the middleware.ts code with it?

I think I just "fixed" this, I had a custom 404 page using the 'not-found.tsx' file. This page was using the Header component I had across the site, which was using some clerk components. As you can see in your logs, and what I had in mine, was the browser is trying to fetch '/_next/static/chunks/app/invalidateCache.js.map' but nextjs static (atleast in dev) doesn't have this file, so returns a 404, serving up the not-found.tsx component. But like with clerkMiddleware() it doesn't bother trying to authenticate this route, so then clerk complains that your trying to use the clerk component in your not-found component.
Basically I just copied over my header in to my not-found.tsx and removed any clerk parts. Next still errors with that file not being found, but atleast clerk doesn't complain.
I think this is both a bug in nextjs of it trying to fetch this .map file that it doesn't have. And with clerk / nextjs middleware not running when hitting the not-found.tsx file.
Maybe another fix is to put the ClerkProvider at the root of the not-found.tsx component, but I haven't tried that.

I have the exact same issue and it does my head in.
